# Timer with seconds minutes hours React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, button, timer

I have been working on a video stream where I need to add timer onPress of stream button. I was able to increment seconds with setInterval() but unable update minutes and hours.
If anyone knows please help.

I have initialized states of all of them to Zero(0).

```
setInterval(() => {
   setSeconds((oldSec) => oldSec + 1);
   console.warn(seconds)
   if (seconds === 10) {
     setMinutes((min) => min + 1);
     clearInterval(setSeconds(0));
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hey, check out this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-timer

Comment: I tried it before but it is throwing some error

Answer (score 0):

You have write this code inside useEffect with dependency array[seconds].

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((oldSec) => oldSec + 1);
      console.warn(seconds)
      if (seconds === 10) {
        setMinutes((min) => min + 1);
        clearInterval(setSeconds(0));
       }
   }, 1000);
  },[seconds]);
```

Comment: reply if this get working

Comment: Can I have this on button press?

Comment: Either way minutes are not being incremented

Comment: This is working for my case perfectly
`useEffect(() => {
if(streaming){
timer = setInterval(() => {
setSeconds((oldSec) => oldSec + 1);
if (seconds === 59) {
setMinutes((min) => min + 1);
setSeconds(0);
}
if(minutes === 59){
setHours((hour) => hour+1);
setSeconds(0);
setMinutes(0);
}
}, 1000);
return () => clearInterval(timer);
}
});`

Comment: you have to use seconds in array dependancy otherwise it will execute on every state update of component.